# Using pg_dump files from 9.3 on 9.5

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Before migrating from an old laptop I created dumpfiles for all of my postgresql/postgis databases using pg_dump.  However after migrating I'm having problems with a lot of errors on import to the new database.  I've realized that my old and new machine are running different versions of postgresql/postgis.  The dumps were created on a machine running postgresql 9.3.13 and postgis version 2.1; I'm trying to recreate the databases on a machine running postgresql 9.5.4 and postgis version 2.2

Any suggestions for getting the data from my dumps to load without problems?  Or for creating new dumps on the old machine which will work across versions?

Comment: All depends what all the problems you got and why? Tables, data, functions all matters. Please specify each problems separately. No one can guess or answer for the database problems which we don't have. Is that right?

Comment: It might help if you gave us the error messages and if possible a snipped of the dump file causing the error.

Comment: As a general advice, you should always use `pg_dump` from the newer version (in your case 9.5) to create the dumps.